# Making a prettier Facebook Login Screen for Parse.com Server with Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, parse-platform, xamarin, facebook-login

Im trying to create a login system for Xamarin.Android to be used on a Parse server. I want to login the user with Facebook and **save** his real name and his **small user photo**.
My current code of displaying the login system is this:

```
using Xamarin.Auth;

loginFacebookButton.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {

            if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
                LoginToFacebook();
            else
            {
                DisplayNoConnectivityMessage();
            }

        };

        loginTwitterButton.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            LoginToTwitter();
        };
    }

    void DisplayNoConnectivityMessage()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert2.SetTitle("Network error");
        alert2.SetMessage("Connection with the Internet is required. Please check your connectivity and try again.");
        alert2.Show();

    }

    void DisplayLoadingMessage(bool Dismiss)
    {
        RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            if (!Dismiss)
            {
                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

                builder.SetTitle("Signing in");
                builder.SetMessage("Please wait...");
                builder.SetCancelable(false);
                alert = builder.Create();
                alert.Show();

            } else {
                if (alert != null)
                    if (alert.IsShowing)
                    { 
                        alert.Dismiss();
                        alert.Dispose();
                    }
            }
        });

    }

    async void LoginToFacebook()
    {
        var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
            clientId: "809804315805408",
            scope: "user_about_me",
            authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/"),
            redirectUrl: new Uri("http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html")
        );

        auth.AllowCancel = false;

        // If authorization succeeds or is canceled, .Completed will be fired.
        auth.Completed += LoginComplete;

        var intent = auth.GetUI(this);
        StartActivity(intent);
    }

    public async void LoginComplete(object sender, AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string id = "";
        string name = "";
        JsonValue obj;
        if (!e.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.SetMessage("Not Authenticated");
            builder.SetPositiveButton("Ok", (o, c) => { });
            builder.Create().Show();
            return;
        }
        else {

            DisplayLoadingMessage(false);
            AccountStore.Create(this) .Save(e.Account, "Facebook");
            // Now that we're logged in, make a OAuth2 request to get the user's info.
            var request = new OAuth2Request("GET", new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/me"), null, e.Account);
            await request.GetResponseAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                var builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                if (t.IsFaulted)
                {
                    builder2.SetTitle("Error");
                    builder2.SetMessage(t.Exception.Flatten().InnerException.ToString());
                    builder2.Show();
                }
                else if (t.IsCanceled)
                {
                    builder2.SetTitle("Task Canceled");
                    builder2.Show();
                }
                else {
                    obj = JsonValue.Parse(t.Result.GetResponseText());
                    id = obj["id"];
                    name = obj["name"];
                }

                builder.SetPositiveButton("Ok", (o, c) => { });
                builder.Create();
            }, UIScheduler);

            var accessToken = e.Account.Properties["access_token"];
            var expiresIn = Convert.ToDouble(e.Account.Properties["expires_in"]);
            var expiryDate = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(expiresIn);
            var user = await ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync(id, accessToken, expiryDate);

            try
            {
                user.Add("Name", name);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("LoginFragment.cs | LoginComplete() :: user.Add (\"Name\",name); :: " + ex.Message);
            }

            var webClient = new WebClient();
            //var httpClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());
            var url = new Uri("http://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=small");
            application.currentUserImageUrl = url.ToString();
            application.currentUserName = name;
            byte[] bytes = null;
            //bytes = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
            bytes = await webClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(url);

            ParseFile saveImageFile = new ParseFile("profileImage.jpg", bytes);
            try
            {
                user.Add("profile_pic", saveImageFile);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("LoginFragment.cs | LoginComplete() :: user.Add (\"profile_pic\",saveImageFile); :: " + ex.Message);
            }

            application.currentUser = user;
            await user.SaveAsync();
            DisplayLoadingMessage(true);
            ChangeScreen();
        }
    }
```

The problem with this code is this:

1. After the login i get a **Success** message displayed (a simple
   success message on a white page) that must be from facebook and
   obviously i dont wnat to be displayed on the user.
2. While the
   **LoginCompete** code is running the app is working on background and the user doesn't see anyhting, its like the app closes and after
   the login opens again. I have try to display an **AlertDialog** with
   the function **DisplayNoConnectivityMessage** but it doesnt be shown
   in the user anything i dont know way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to login with Facebook on Parse is the official [Parse SDK](http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/dotnet/guide/) in combination with the offical Facebook for Android SDK to handle the Single-Sign On Scenario.

With just some small steps you achieve the expected result:

1. Follow this small guide to setup your app for the Facebook SDK: https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/facebookandroid
2. Setup the Parse SDK

   ```
   public App()
   {
       // App.xaml initialization
       ParseClient.Initialize("Your Application ID", "Your .NET Key");
       ParseFacebookUtils.Initialize("Your Facebook App Id");
       // Other initialization
   }
   ```
3. Add a FB Login Button to your View.

   ```
   <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
     android:id="@+id/login_button"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
     android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
   ```
4. Get the callback and use the token to signin the user with Parse.

   ```
   public class MainActivity : Activity, IFacebookCallback
   {
       protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
       {
           base.OnCreate(bundle);

           // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
           // SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

           var callbackManager = CallbackManagerFactory.Create();

           var loginButton = FindViewById<LoginButton>(Resource.Id.login_button);
           loginButton.RegisterCallback(callbackManager, this);
       }

       #region IFacebookCallback

       public void OnCancel()
       {
           // Handle Cancel
       }

       public void OnError(FacebookException error)
       {
           // Handle Error
       }

       public async void OnSuccess(Object result)
       {
           // We know that this is a LoginResult
           var loginResult = (LoginResult) result;

           // Convert Java.Util.Date to DateTime
           var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
           var expireDate = epoch.AddMilliseconds(loginResult.AccessToken.Expires.Time);

           // FB User AccessToken
           var accessToken = loginResult.AccessToken.Token;

           ParseUser user = await ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync("Your Facebook App Id", accessToken, expireDate);
       }

       #endregion
   ... 
   }
   ```
5. (Optional) Interact with the Facebook SDK & ParseUser

   ```
   // You can simply pass the acquired AccessToken to the GraphRequest
   var parameters = new Bundle();
   parameters.PutString("fields", "id,email,gender,cover,picture.type(small)");
   var request = new GraphRequest(loginResult.AccessToken, "me", parameters, HttpMethod.Get);

   // Execute request and Handle response (See FB Android SDK Guide)
   // to get image as byte[] from GraphResponse
   byte[] data;

   // Store the image into the ParseUser
   user["image"] = new ParseFile("image.jpg", data);
   ```

> Instead of using the GraphRequest you can always fallback to the `HttpClient` / WebClient and pass the AccessToken as URL parameter. [Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/)

**Additional**

Here a link to the official docs: http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/dotnet/guide/#facebook-users

Pick SDK from Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Facebook.Android/

The Xamarin Facebook Android SDK works like the Java SDK so this docs are also worth to look at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android#addbutton

Comment: your parsefacebookutil code example is from java, in c# it doesnt have those arguments (ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync(string FaceBookID, string AccessToken, DateTime expiration)) and it doesnt provide an UI.also i want a way to save the user image, with facebook sdk examples i only see a way to display user image, not to save it

Comment: You're right, that the advanced solution is a Java Example which need some custom jar bindings to work with Xamarin. Nevertheless you can use the above simple solution. Make sure so open the browser before calling `ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync(browser, null);` to see the OAuth Login Page. You can than use the FB Sdk or HttpClient to grab the image from the Graph API and save it in the ParseUser with `user["image"] = new ParseFile("userimage.jpg", data);` where data is the `byte[]` of the downloaded image.

Comment: but ParseFacebookUtils for c# doesnt have a consrtructor that takes browser, null for arguments, how then i can do that?

Comment: I`m really sorry. I took this from an older app of mine. I updated to the most recent SDK version and now saw that they have changed the API a little bit. I will update the answer asap.

Comment: thanks, i will test your code asap however it would be nice if i could find a solution using Xamarin.Auth cause i want to make more ways to login with other websites also and i will probably come to the same problem again

Answer (score 2):

My problem finally was:

1. By disabling secure browsing on facebook login application settings from facebook developers dashboard, i was able to get rib of the success message.
2. Setting the Activity to "**NoHistory = true**", makes social login problematic cause the responds from the social platforms to the Activity isn't tracked as it should. Also this was the problem for not showing the AlertDialog (i would never going to guess that).

But the answer of **@paul-reichelt** is the best approach for native facebook login.